# Can a node join multiple Business Network in Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

So theoretically it is possible for a node to be in multiple business networks,But is that practically possible?How can a node install multiple Cordapps if they are members of two different business networks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for a node to join multiple Business Network. Of course all of them has to be part of the same Corda network. (Yes a node cannot be member more than Corda network).

And definitely node can install many CorDapps. This was the original vision of a Corda network, indeed.

How to install multiply CordApps? Just copy all required jars to the `cordapps` directory.

Comment: So is it an automated process that upon joining a business network Cordapp will be automatically installed or should we do it manually?And also how is these cordapp jars get available.

Comment: @Sil Installing CorDapp is technical part. Joining business network is a contractual one. Business Network might provide an automated way, but I generally assume a manual process, especially when you want to join more than one network.